# Java: Let GUI change between different states with pauses

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

Is there a way in Java to let the GUI change between several states but pause shortly between each change, so that it will appear like an animation? (without using JavaFX pre-defined animations)

As a simple example: Let's have an array with 100 strings. Every 50 milliseconds the string depicted in the GUI/textfield should change, iterating through the given array. At the same time the GUI should remain responsive and the 'animation' should be stoppable by a button click.

Is there a way other than using Thread.wait() or sleep() or is this the only possible option in Java? How can the GUI remain responsive?

Comment: You should take a look at [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: `Thread.wait()` or `sleep()` are not even _options_. Forget you ever heard of them in GUI code.

Comment: @BackSlash Why should he mix Swing with JavaFX?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to animate the GUI.  Your example will go through the array of 100 strings in 5 seconds.  No one will be able to read the strings.  Take a look at my [Java Swing Marquee](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=681) article to see how to create an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit outdated, but have a look at [this class](https://github.com/GlenErrands/memorygame/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/glenerrands/memorygame/Tile.java). The `paint` method is overridden and does its work dependent on the `turnFactor`, which is altered in the desired rythm by a second thread:

```
/**
 * A single, flippable tile in the GUI of the memory game.
 */
public class Tile extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3832294699261778944L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tile.class);

    private final TileGroup _tileGroup;

    private float turnFactor = -1.0f;

    private boolean flipping = false;

    private boolean uncovered = false;

    public Tile(TileGroup tileGroup) {
        _tileGroup = tileGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        LOGGER.trace("drawing..." + getX() + "/" + getY() + " " + getWidth() + "x" + getHeight());
        final Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        final int y = 0;
        if (turnFactor > 0) {
            final BufferedImage image = getTileGroup().getImage();
            final float scale = Math.min(((float) getWidth()) / image.getWidth(),
                    ((float) getHeight()) / image.getHeight());
            final int x = Math.round((getWidth() / 2.0f) - (image.getWidth() * scale * turnFactor * 0.5f));
            final AffineTransform translateInstance = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
            final AffineTransform scaleInstance = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(turnFactor * scale, scale);
            translateInstance.concatenate(scaleInstance);
            graphics2d.drawImage(image, translateInstance, null);
            // graphics2d.drawImage(getTileGroup().getImage(), x, y, width,
            // height, null);
        } else {
            final int x = Math.round((getWidth() / 2.0f) * (1.0f - Math.abs(turnFactor)));
            final int width = Math.round(getWidth() * Math.abs(turnFactor)) - 1;
            final int height = getHeight() - 1;
            graphics2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.GRAY, 0, height * 2, Color.BLUE));
            graphics2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void flip() {
        if (!isFlipping()) {
            setFlipping(true);
            final boolean uncovered = isUncovered();
            setUncovered(!uncovered);
            Thread t = new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
                if (uncovered) {
                    LOGGER.debug("covering tile");
                    for (turnFactor = 1.0f; turnFactor > -1.0; turnFactor -= 0.1) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(15);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("interrupted", e);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                } else {
                    LOGGER.debug("uncovering tile");
                    for (turnFactor = -1.0f; turnFactor < 1.0; turnFactor += 0.1) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(15);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("interrupted", e);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
                setFlipping(false);
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public TileGroup getTileGroup() {
        return _tileGroup;
    }

    public boolean isFlipping() {
        return flipping;
    }

    public void setFlipping(boolean flipping) {
        this.flipping = flipping;
    }

    public boolean isUncovered() {
        return uncovered;
    }

    public void setUncovered(boolean uncovered) {
        this.uncovered = uncovered;
    }

}
```

Is this what you are looking for?